# Remove top padding in ListView put inside scaffold with no appBar

Tags: flutter, listview

I had an unwanted top padding in listview inside scaffold that has no appbar and I want to delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14842:

Just wrap the listview with MediaQuery.removePadding widget like that:

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
                      context: context,
                      removeTop: true,
                      child: ListView()
                    );
```